# UWP Background Audio fails because RPC server is unavailable

Tags: c#, background, win-universal-app, background-task, background-audio

I am implementing the UWP sample for background audio on Github, but with no success. I copy and pasted everything, and while it works in the sample, it doesn't work on my project. Every time the CurrentPlayer object (type is a MediaPlayer), it calls teh existing BackgroundMediaPlayer. But that one always crashes because the RPC server is unavailable. I have no idea what this means or why, because it does work in the sample, even though I copied the code (I even imported the BackgroundAudioTask and BackgroundShared projects without changing any of the code)

I hosted the [full code on GitHub](https://github.com/arnvanhoutte/MusicTest), because it might be more useful than my description. I've been stuck on this for months now, so help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is Background Task a WindowsRuntime component? Because that is the major mistake people do.

Comment: Yes it is a runtime component. I even imported the project from the sample, so it's exactly the same

Comment: Ok. I ll check the code and let you know

Comment: Thank you! The only thing that I made is the mainpage.xaml.cs code

Comment: unable to run the project . getting lots of errors. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E4A5FCCA92E37830!486&authkey=!AKtxW2hxvx5lDfg&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: That's weird. Do you have everything necessary in VS installed to run UWP apps?

Comment: What build are you running? I am on the latest insider build for W10, maybe that is a reason why?

Comment: I have visual studio update 2 pending. I'll update  and get back to you

Comment: Okay, maybe if that doesn't work you could try to add the references again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded and checked your code,everything is proper except you dint add background task reference to your main project

**You need to do add** `BackgroundPlayer` **refernce to your mainproject(musictest)**